# How to remove the element in dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, splice

```
{"success":true,
"alldata": [
    {"name":"a","location":"market","age":12,"hobby":"singing","point":99.83},
    {"name":"b","location":"home","age":23,"hobby":"football","point":99.98},
    {"name":"c","location":"drugstore","age":17,"hobby":"game","point":99.99},
    ........ ,
    {"name":"z","location":"school","age":15,"hobby":"piano","point":100}
    ]
}
```

The data above is on a website

I want it to parse at google spreadsheet

```
var url = "website address"

function getdata() { 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('fetching...'); 

    try { 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 
    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
    var data = {}; 

        if (json && json.alldata) { 
            json.alldata.forEach(function(elem) { 
            data[elem.name] = elem}); 
            } 


        sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('success'); 
        sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(JSON.stringify(data)); 
        }
        catch(ex) {sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('error');} 
        }
```

I succeeded until this

But the 'alldata' on the website is getting too large

and I got an error message on sheet

```
"You entered more than 50,000 characters in a single cell."
```

So, I want to erase 'location' and 'point'

But I don't know how can I do that

```
delete json.alldata["location"]
```

I tried it but didn't work

```
for(var i = 0; i<json.alldata.length;i++){
    if(json.alldata[i][1] == "location"){
    json.alldata[i].splice(1.1);
    }
{
```

I also tried but didn't work

How can I do this? please help..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i<json.alldata.length;i++){
    delete json.alldata[i]["location"];
}
```

should work.

Comment: Wow now It works! maybe I made any mistake by syntax!! Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Objectif.assign to create a  New object with the values you want in it,  take alook at the  [Object.assign documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 0):

The functional and cleanest way to do this is

```
var newdata = json.alldata.map((obj)=>{delete obj.location; return obj})
```

Comment: where should I add this code? I got 'Syntax error.'

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to return the object.

Comment: That's ok. I also make a mistake :) but still Syntax error... :(

Comment: "functional" does not include mutation of data, this might work but certainly using `.map` does not make it functional

Comment: Since the objects aren't being cloned, yes, you're right. Data is getting mutated and it isn't functional.